# Error accessing document property

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, document

I am just starting with node.js, typescript and VS Code but I run into a problem when trying the examples given by typescript (for example the greeter.ts)

I can transpile using command line or VS Code menu, and run the product by clicking the html given in the example (this then loads the script.js file).

If I try to run / debug from inside VS Code an exception is caught on the (only) line "document.body.innerHTML = greeter.greet();"
For some reason the "document" property does not exist (yet?).

The same happens with the raytracer example. Compiled and dragged into a browser is fine, started from VS Code isn't.

Any idea how to create a simple example that runs (debugs) in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript examples are meant to be run in a browser.

`document` is an API that is exposed by the browser to the JavaScript engine that allows JS code to read and modify the webpage. Since Node.js isn't a browser, it doesn't have the document property.

Comment: I'd like to ask two follow-up questions in this case: 1) If I only want to develop for a browser, do I need to install node.js onto my dev machine at all? 2) Can I configure VS Code to run my app in a browser window (and also debug with it)?

Comment: @Ralf 1) If you are only developing client-side apps, then no, you don't. 2) Yes, that is possible using an [extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug). According to Microsoft's blog post, they are looking at supporting Edge and other browsers in the future.